# Comparing non-git project with a git repo

Tags: git, diff

I have a project that was always manually deployed to a server without Git (as the server was behind a firewall that could not access Bitbucket), even though the project is managed on Bitbucket on my local machine.

Because of the manual deploy, there is a chance that I may have some differences in the code, and **I want to compare the entire repo with the files on the file system.**

My initial thought is to download all the files from the server, make a new git repository of those files and then do a git-diff, but I was wondering if there was a less laborious way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking out / cloning the git repo, then download all the server files over its file / directory structure, and then just run `git diff` at that point?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, it is not much different from my current way of thinking, but the problem with that is that I can't access the server via FTP or SSH. I need to use a VM to connect to the server where the files are located. Then, I need to download to the VM, then mount a local drive to VMWare to get the files to my own machine. I was more thinking of doing it on the server (so checkout the repo there, and then just compare file system with repo, but not sure how,as git-diff typically works with repos, right? Not sure how to make it compare with raw text on the server.